# Rewrite Rule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I redirect all basic http requests to use https and this works however when I try to use www.example.com it fails, it only works for the url example.com or http://example.com.  This is my code:

```
 # for main domain
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]s
```